# Using an attribute of an object in a separate class to determine if it's there

Tags: java

I am trying to check if a user's input is part of an object of a different method's attributes. In other words, I am asking a user for an input of a name, and I want to check if that name exists as an attribute of a person. I have a method in the person class to check if the name exists, but I am not sure about how to go about executing the method.

my first class:

```
userInput = "xxx";
if(????? == -1){
    System.out.println("Person is nowhere to be found :(");
}
```

Second Class:

```
int FindPersonName(String person)
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < totalPersonCount ; i++)
    {
        if (person[i].getName().equals(person))
            {
            System.out.println(person[i].getName());
            return person[i].getName() //Defined elsewhere
            }
    }

    System.out.println(person + " does not exist in person list.");
    return -1;
}
```

So my question is this: What goes in the ???? for the first class?

EDIT: Now getting an error saying that non-static method cannot be referenced from a non static context??

EDIT AGAIN: Thanks guys :D made the method FindBoatNames static, and in the if statement did Fleet.FindBoatNames(userInput) == -1, and it worked perfect.

Comment: What type is person[]  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are in both class

```
if(FindPersonName(userInput ) == -1){

}
```

or different classes and that is **not an static method** you need to create an object.

Like

```
 if(new ClassOfThatMethod().FindPersonName(userInput) == -1){

    }
```

P.S. follow java naming conventions, method name starts with lower case. `FindPersonName` should be `findPersonName`

Answer (score 2):

Do like this

```
if(obj.FindPersonName(userInput)==-1){

}
```

Or make FindPersonName() method as static and call like below

```
if(FindPersonName(userInput)==-1){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
userInput = "xxx";
if(findPersonByName(userInput) == -1){
     System.out.println("Person is nowhere to be found :(");
} else {
     System.out.println("Person found with id");
}
```

But you need to return another integer than -1 in the second class:

```
int FindPersonName(String person)
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < totalPersonCount ; i++)
    {
        if (person[i].getName().equals(person))
            {
                 System.out.println(person[i].getName());
                 return 1;
            }
    }

    System.out.println(person + " does not exist in person list.");
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this

```
if(FindPersonName(userInput ) == -1){

}
```

but one more thing is `int FindPersonName(String person)` will always return `-1`

you should change your `FindPersonName(String person)` in this way

```
int FindPersonName(String person)
{    

    for (int i = 0 ; i < totalPersonCount ; i++)
    {
        if (person[i].getName().equals(person))
            {
            System.out.println(person[i].getName());
             return 1;// return something positive if person found
            }
    }

    System.out.println(person + " does not exist in person list.");
    return -1;
}
```